# Loop with datetime

Tags: python, json, loops, datetime, request

I would like to retrieve information on three different dates. For that I created a loop:

```
date = datetime.datetime.now()
date7 = date + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
date7 = date7.strftime("%Y%m%d")
date14 = date + datetime.timedelta(days=14)
date14 = date14.strftime("%Y%m%d")
dates=[]
dates.append(date7)
dates.append(date14)
dates.append(date21)

for i in dates :
  url = "https://X{}".format(dates)
  url_request = requests.get(url)
  url_request_data = url_request.json()
  print(len(url_request_data["departures"]))
```

And I get the error

> "KeyError: 'departures'."

However, when I try this code without looping (testing with a single date) it works.
Could someone help me please? I am lost

Comment: Firstly, you're putting an array of dates into the `url` string, what URL are you trying to make? Second, print out the value of `url_request_data` and see whats in it, if it is a valid URL.

Comment: when defining url, instead of passing each item in the list, you are passing list itself every time

Comment: any reason why you're using format instead of f-strings here?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the array into the url, instead of passing in the `i` variable that changes on each iteration - see below:

```py
for i in dates:
    url = "https://X{}".format(i) # i instead of dates
    # ... etc
```

This will insert each date individually instead of as an array.